# POST/GET request from postman to Microsoft Dynamics crm 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, postman, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I was trying to create entity using Web API. So using my instance url, client_id, client_secret I can successfully generate access token and refresh token. But whenever I try to make any post request using that access_token, I get 401(unauthorized) status.
I was trying to create new entity from postman like this:
url: `https://myurldomain.crm5.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts`

headers:

```
POST /api/data/v9.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Host: myinstancename.crm5.dynamics.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
Authorization: Bearer  mytoken
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Accept: application/json
```

**[copied from postman code section**]
Body:

```
{
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "creditonhold": false,
    "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
    "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
    "revenue": 5000000,
    "accountcategorycode": 1
}
```

While send request, I constantly get  401 unauthorized response.
Any suggestion please?
I am following their  [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/perform-operations-web-api)

Comment: Does this help:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/setup-postman-environment. Followed it few days ago and it worked for me.

Comment: Did you assign a security role that gives permissions to the user account to create a record?

Comment: @ Eccountable, no. I haven't seen such permission. where to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the MS documentation to setup the Postman environment & using the same to perform operations: [Use Postman with the Dynamics 365 Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/use-postman-web-api)

When you setup the Postman environment, make sure you use the CRM user credentials in Azure AD signin challenge popup, which has minimum of one security role covering the necessary privileges in CRM. If you are able to create an Account record in CRM UI, then use your credentials in Postman too.

To manage roles for any CRM user you are using to connect in Postman, check that User profile in CRM under Settings - Security - Users. Start with Sales person role if you want.

[Assign a security role to a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/create-users-assign-online-security-roles#assign-a-security-role-to-a-user)

Getting a token is first part handled by O365 & AAD for any valid AD user, but the API request uses that token & issue the web api to CRM online platform where the CRM security model will kick in & authorize the data access.

Comment: Hi Arun, I'm not using AD with my trial.Using Get and Post requests, all I get is 200OK. I don't know where my response data is. Any thoughts?

Comment: @priyeshwagh777 can you ask a new question, with all details like request, screenshot, etc

Comment: Sorry to say, got banned from asking a new question on StackOverflow for some reason.

Comment: I'm using NTLM method by just entering username and password, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I guess do I need to do it from registering in Azure?

Comment: @priyeshwagh777 not sure, I just tried the beta NTLM - i'm getting 401 :) will try later & update you

Comment: Sure @arun! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of postman added the support for NTLM authentication(although its still a beta version). Are you using NTLM authentication from postman to call Crm Dynamics web api. If not try using that and it asks for Domain name inaddition to username and password. Hopefully this helps with your authentication problems.